# $11$ students have formed $5$ study groups. How to find 2 students $A$ and $B$ such that every study group which includes $A$ also includes $B$?

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Eleven students have formed five study groups in a summer camp . Prove that two students can be found   say $A$ qnd $B$ , such that every study group which includes student $A$ also includes student $B$.
The solution given in the book is as follows:

> We can number the study groups with numbers ${1,2,3,4,5}$.Then instead of considering each student him or herself,  we can consider the sef of numbers belonging to the study group he or she part of   .  We solve the problem by dividing $32$ subsets into $10$ collections such thaf if two subsets are chosen from ghis collection , one of them contains the other . The following is such a collection :
> [$\phi$,{1},{1,3},{1,2,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4,5}],
> [{2},{2,5},{1,2,5},{1,2,3,5}],
> [{3},{1,3},{1,3,4},{1,3,4,5}]
> [{4},{1,4},{1,2,4},{1,2,4,5}]
> [{5},{1,5},{1,3,5}],
> [{2,4},{2,4,5},{2,3,4,5}],
> [{3,4},{3,4,5}],
> [{3,5},{2,3,5}],
> [{4,5},{1,4,5}]
> [{2,3},{2,3,4}].

Well, can someone please tell how to construct such a collection ....I mean how to arrive at such a collection so that it gives us the required result...is thee a way? I mean what is the idea behind it?I am not quite getting the idea behind it...I mean the way to construct such a collection of subsets

Comment: Don’t mangle your title just to fit the whole question there. Hint: The title does not need to be the whole question, and the body of the question should contain the whole question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for sharing! I thought it might have created some confusion so I chose to post in that way....

Comment: No, edit it. It reads horribly.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Do u think that'll be alright? If i do it... wont it confuse the readers ? I mean its alright anyways....besides I am looking for an answer....

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have already edited it...I think the issue is now resolved....

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative solution to your problem.

We can think of every student as a subset of $S= \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and suppose that for each two $A$ and $B$ there is an $x\in S$ that is in $A$ and not in $B$ and $y\in S$ that is in $B$ and not in $A$, i.e. $A$ and $B$ does not contain the other. Then by [Sperner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem) we can have at most ${5\choose 2}=10$ such sets. A contradiction.

And you don't need to construct anything.

Comment: that's a nice solution but can u please explain that when u say that the no. of such sets possible at maximum is $10$ ...well  but here we are partitioning into $5$ groups so where do u get the contradiction?